# Fire a trigger when Label Content changes

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I've just started to learn WPF and now I'm doing my second WPF application with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I want to fire an animation when Label's Content changes. I have 81 labels on my View and I want to associate the same animation to all of them.

This is one of my labels, but all of them are mostly identical:

```
<Label x:Name="c00" Content="{Binding BestIndividual[0]}" Margin="0" BorderThickness="2,2,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" />
```

Searching, I have found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27056594/68571), but I don't know how to applied to what I need.

I think I have found how to do it in this article: [How to: Trigger an Animation When a Property Value Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-trigger-an-animation-when-a-property-value-changes).

But, who can I fire a trigger when Label's Content change?

The only way that I've found about how to fire a trigger is when a property has a value:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
```

Comment: I don't think 81 similar Labels in a View is a good idea. To display a collection use ItemsControl

Comment: @ASh Thanks, I've just started to learn WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EventTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)s are meant for executing actions - animation included - in response to a [routed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedevent(v=vs.110).aspx).

As [mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252182/mm8) suggested, the `Label` control has no "*ContentChanged*" event. But instead of using a normal event, you can implement a routed one:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ContentChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "ContentChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CustomLabel));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ContentChanged
    {
        add
        {
            AddHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            RemoveHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ContentChangedEvent));
    }
}
```

In this way you can create a `Style` with an `EventTrigger` for beginning an animation:

```
<Style x:Key="ContentChangedAnimated" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomLabel}"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentChanged">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" 
                                            To="28" AutoReverse="True" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then you need to apply that style to your (Custom)Labels:

```
<local:CustomLabel x:Name="c00" Content="{Binding BestIndividual[0]}" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ContentChangedAnimated}"
        BorderThickness="2,2,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" />
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The `Label` class has no "ContentChanged" event but you could define your own custom `Label` class and override the `OnContentChanged` method:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public event EventHandler ContentChanged;

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        if (ContentChanged != null)
            ContentChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In the XAML you replace all `Label` elements with your custom type:

```
<local:CustomLabel x:Name="c00" Content="{Binding BestIndividual[0]}" ContentChanged="OnContentChanged" />
```

You could then perform the animation programmatically in the event handler.