# Animation to flash a colour and come back to its original one

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I'm developing a WPF application with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I have this animation:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentChanged">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                To="Yellow" AutoReverse="True" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I'm trying to change the background colour to yellow, and then come back to white again, but I think `AutoReverse` doesn't mean that.

I have also tried:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                To="Yellow" FillBehavior="Stop" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    From="Yellow" To="White"
                    BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="0:0:1"/>
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

But, at the end, the background colour is yellow.

The effect I'm trying to achieve is to change background colour when Label's content changes, and then come back quickly to its original colour. I want to create a visual effect to notice which label has changed its content.

How can I change the colour to yellow and then change it to white again?

Comment: have you tried using EventTrigger.ExitAction

Comment: Maybe, an answer is here: https://wpf.2000things.com/2017/03/19/1202-using-a-color-animation-to-draw-emphasis-to-something/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `ColorAnimation` to the `Storyboard` and set its `BeginTime` property to a value greater than or equal to the `Duration` of the first one, e.g.:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentChanged">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:1" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                To="Yellow"/>
                <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:0:1" Duration="0:0:1" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                To="White"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

Comment: Maybe I have edited the question while you are answering. Sorry.

Comment: @VansFannel: I am not sure I follow. My example first animates the background to Yellow and then back to White. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Yes, but it remains yellow. I have 81 labels, and all of them use the same style. At the beginning all of these 81 labels changes very quickly, but later on, only a few of them changes. But, the ones that don't change remains yellow.

Comment: @VansFannel: It works just fine for me. Your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have provided. Your last comment doesn't make much sense without a [reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, I can't upload my solution to let you see what happens. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure that the ContentChanged event - whatever that is - is actually fired for these?

Comment: I get the `ContentChanged` from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51136302/68571. And I think it is fired, because the colour changes to yellow.